# ITextSharp - Google Chrome Save Button Saves PDF as .ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, .net-3.5, itext

I am currently using ITextSharp to create a PDF using a .Net 3.5 ASPX page.  Everything works well.. the only issue is that in chrome(Version 42.0.2311.135) when I click the save button or right click and say save as it tries to save as an .aspx page.  I don't experience these issues when using Firefox or Internet Explorer. I tried disabling the chrome PDF viewer and it just automatically saves the file as an aspx file.  I've included my code below which is fired from a button click.  I am assuming it is the way I am handling the response? Any ideas?

[image]

```
iTextSharp.text.Document d = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);

using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{

 w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, stream);

 //add stuff to itext document

 d.Close();

 byte[] b = stream.ToArray();
 stream.Close();


 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.BinaryWrite(b);
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Wanted to share my findings in case it saves someone the headache. Adding Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=myfilename.pdf"); fixed most of the issues but I was still experiencing a problem with the save button in the Google chrome viewer(print worked fine but save prompted the user to save the page and not the pdf).  The PDF is being generated on a .aspx page through a button click.  After it is generated I clear the response and dump the PDF to the page.  The form element on the page didn't have a method set so it was being sent as post(found this out through fiddler). This page was being shared through an iframe.  I changed the method to GET on the page and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.pdf");
```

Comment: This fixes the issue but the file is automatically downloaded.  Is there a way to display it in the browser and allow for saving as PDF via the save button provided by the chrome viewer?

Comment: I tried using inline instead and I get the same results as before.  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;inline=myfilename.pdf");

Comment: Then "inline" is your friend. Maybe the page is cached, try deleting browser cache and reloading.

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem even after deleting browser cache and reloading :( My above comment had a typo as well.  I have this in my code: "Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=filename.pdf"

Comment: Ok I found out the issue is that the above page is displayed in an iframe.. Sorry I didn't mention before because the results were the same when looking at the page directly. It is unfortunately this way because it is being hosted through a Portlet on an existing site.  So if I navigate to the page directly it works as expected.  I'm marking your answer as correct because it solved my issue.  However any ideas about getting the save button to work for the PDF that is displayed in an iframe?